# Debug console text in yellow

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

so when I debug a program on visual studio community 2019, the debug console text is appearing in yellow, would it be possible to change that color to white? (I might have changed it before, but I don't remember how...).

Here is a picture of the output window:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on top of console window -> choose 'Properties' -> 'Colors' -> 'Screen text' and pick desired color for your console.
You should see something like this:

[image: Console Properties]